# How do you insert information in a table if you have a unary relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, insert, relationship

```
create table Employee(
    staff_id_employee int primary key ,
    gender char(1) check (gender in('F','M')),
    staff_id int foreign key REFERENCES Staff(staff_id),
    manager_id int foreign key references Employee(staff_id_employee)
);
```

How do I insert the information in this table.***The text to this is that an employee manages other employees***.If anyone could give me some sort of example cuz I don't know what to write instead of the question marks '????'.WHat is the value to manager_id in this case

```
INSERT into Employee(staff_id_employee, gender, staff_id, manager_id) VALUES (30000,'F',6007,????)
```

Comment: But I must add a value to the manager cuz the employees do have an employee who manages them in my case

Comment: This is not called a unary relationship, it's a self-referencing relationship. Insert the manager first, with `null` for `manager_id`

Comment: The thing is in the diagrams it created a unary relationship with this code but I am only having problems on what I must insert at the manager_id value

Comment: If the employee has no manager then you set that value to NULL or -1 or something you know will never be a value for `staff_id_employee`.  If the employee has a manager then you use the value of `staff_id_employee` on the manager's record in the `Employee` table.

Comment: Presumably if the employee has a manager you know the staff_id of the manager?

Comment: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint "FK__Employee__manag__38996AB5".-----This is what it shows when I use the value of staff_id_employee on the manager's record in the Employee table

Comment: It does have a manager but it's created on this table therefore I don't know what ID I should set since it's unary

Comment: According to the schema definition you posted the FK relationship for `manager_id` points to `staff_id_employee`, therefore any value for `manager_id` MUST be an existing value in the `staff_id_employee` column.  If you're getting a FK violation then you're either 1) not entering a value for `manager_id` from the list of values in `staff_id_employee` or 2) your table schema is different from what you actually posted.

Comment: It's actually the exact schema but it still has the same error

Comment: Perhaps throw in some sample data to your question and demonstrate with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I just need to know how to insert info in a table with unary relationship...

Comment: Everything we've told you so far is what you need in order to enter your data.  All of this works with your posted table schema.  You can call it a unary relationship, it is also called a recursive relationship or self-referencing relationship.  In either case, the comments and answers already posted describe what you're asking for.  Update your question with EXACTLY the data and code you're working with and we can help you further.

Comment: Works fine for me https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=980e12324eb0e0c8edb165c6bf5bd9f9 not sure what your issue is. You seem to have a hangup about a unary relationship, I suggest you just forget you heard that term

Answer (score 2):

If you need to look-up the manager's Id then you want an `insert select`

```
INSERT into Employee(staff_id_employee, gender, staff_id, manager_id) 
SELECT 30000,'F',6007, staff_id_employee
from Employee
where staff_id = [Manager's staff ID]
```

Answer (score 0):

If Employee 3000 doesn't have a manager, you would typically insert a null

```
INSERT into Employee(staff_id_employee, gender, staff_id, manager_id) 
             VALUES (30000,'F',6007, null)
```

Otherwise insert the manager's ID.

Comment: Do I have to insert a special ID since I am working with unary relationship